# Merging two frames into one frame in pyqt5

Tags: python, pyqt5

I am teaching myself Python GUI ideas and am trying to make my own application from scratch to learn some of the basic ideas.

I'm trying to figure out inheritance and passing stuff from one object to another, and to do so I've created the following code which has a lot of classes passing stuff from one to another then bundling it up with `QMainWindow`.

How can I merge two frames (`leftFrameContainer` and `rightFrameContainer`) together under the `mergeFrameContainer` so I can pass it to my main window and set it as my central widget?

```
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QFrame, QHBoxLayout, QMenu, QMenuBar


# Define the main UI window and call instantiating methods
class mainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        createMenuBar.__init__(self)
        windowInitialize.__init__(self)
        mergedFrameContainer.__init__(self)

# Setup the initial size and other attributes of the mainWindow
class windowInitialize(mainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        self.setGeometry(15, 40, 1250, 625)
        
# Create menu bars for mainWindow
class createMenuBar(mainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        menuBar = self.menuBar()
        
        # Set the menu font size
        menuFont=menuBar.font()
        menuFont.setPointSize(6)
        menuBar.setFont(menuFont)
        
        # Creating 'File' menu option and adding to menuBar
        fileMenu = QMenu("&File", self)
        menuBar.addMenu(fileMenu)

        # Creating 'Options' menu option and adding to menuBar
        optionsMenu = menuBar.addMenu("&Options")
        menuBar.addMenu(optionsMenu)

        # Creating 'View' menu option and adding to menuBar
        viewMenu = menuBar.addMenu("&View")
        menuBar.addMenu(viewMenu)

        # Creating 'Create' menu option and adding to menuBar
        createMenu = menuBar.addMenu("&Create")
        menuBar.addMenu(createMenu)

        # Creating 'Help' menu option and adding to menuBar
        helpMenu = menuBar.addMenu("&Help")
        menuBar.addMenu(helpMenu)
        
# Create the left frame container for the mainWindow
class leftFrameContainer():
    def __init__(self):
        leftFrame = self.QFrame()
        leftFrame.setFrameStyle(QFrame.NoFrame)
        leftFrame.setStyleSheet('background-color:lightgray')
        
# Create the right frame container for the mainWindow
class rightFrameContainer():
    def __init__(self):
        rightFrame = self.QFrame()
        rightFrame.setFrameStyle(QFrame.NoFrame)
        rightFrame.setStyleSheet('background-color:gray')
    
# Merge the right and left frame containers and set in the centralWidget of
# the mainWindow
class mergedFrameContainer(mainWindow):
    def __init__(self):       
        mergedFrame = self.QFrame()
        mergedFrame.addWidget(leftFrameContainer)
        mergedFrame.addWidget(rightFrameContainer)
        
        hbox = QHBoxLayout()
        hbox.addWidget(mergedFrameContainer)
        self.centralWidget().setLayout(hbox)
        self.show()

        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = mainWindow()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are many issues with your code, and I'm under the impression that you've not yet really understood how classes, instances and inheritance work.

For starters, the `windowInitialize` and `createMenuBar` don't make a lot of sense as classes, as long as they're used like that (explicitly calling their `__init__` but out of its context) : according to your code, it seems that you actually don't need those classes at all, and you should just transform those `__init__` methods to standard methods of `mainWindow` (which, by the way, being it a class should be named `MainWindow`):

```py
class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.windowInitialize()
        self.createMenuBar()

    def windowInitialize(self):
        self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon("honeywellIcon.png"))
        self.setWindowTitle("Materials Database")
        self.setGeometry(15, 40, 1250, 625)
        
    def createMenuBar(self):
        menuBar = self.menuBar()
        # etc...
```

<sup>Note that functions are normally created for 3 main reasons: 1. they may or may not be called depending on the situation, or even called more than once; 2. in case of methods, if the possibility overriding must be provided; 3. to make code more organized, tidy, readable and maintainable. In your code, the only *partially* valid reason is the third one, but with a few improvements even that might not be enough.</sup>

Now, to the point. The frame "merging" part has various problems:

- `leftFrameContainer` and `rightFrameContainer` are *classes*, you cannot add classes to widgets and layouts, only instances;
- they do not inherit from QWidget, and you can only add instances of QWidget (or of its subclasses) to a widget or layout;
- `self` has no `QFrame` attribute;
- [`setCentralWidget()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmainwindow.html#setCentralWidget) was never called, so `centralWidget()` returns `None` and it will crash since `None` has no `setLayout` attribute;

In the following example I'll show a proper way of using subclassing that displays the difference between the original class and the subclassed one.

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    # ... as above


# since the two frame share similar aspects, let's create a common class

class BaseFrameContainer(QtWidgets.QFrame):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setFrameStyle(self.NoFrame)


class LeftFrameContainer(BaseFrameContainer):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setStyleSheet('''
            BaseFrameContainer { 
                background-color: lightgray; 
            }
        ''')


class RightFrameContainer(BaseFrameContainer):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setStyleSheet('''
            BaseFrameContainer { 
                background-color: gray; 
            }
        ''')


class MainWindowWithFrames(MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        central = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(central)

        self.leftFrameContainer = LeftFrameContainer()
        self.rightFrameContainer = RightFrameContainer()

        layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(central)
        layout.addWidget(self.leftFrameContainer)
        layout.addWidget(self.rightFrameContainer)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    originalWin = MainWindow()
    originalWin.show()
    subclassWin = MainWindowWithFrames()
    subclassWin.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The code above will open two windows, the first one is the original `MainWindow` subclass, without "merged frames", the second is a subclass of `MainWindow` that *does* add the frames. The benefit of subclassing your own [sub]classes is that you may make *specialized* versions of a class that implements different things.

For instance, knowing that the `__init__` of `MainWindow` (and its subclasses) always calls `createMenuBar`, then you can change its behavior:

```py
class MainWindowWithFrames(MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        # ... as above

    def createMenuBar(self):
        super().createMenuBar() # create the default menu of MainWindow
        customMenu = self.menuBar().addMenu('Custom menu') # add a menu
        customMenu.addAction('Custom action')
```

Further suggestions:

- try to use consistent imports: if you import the Qt submodules, it makes little sense to also import individual classes (and vice versa), and it also makes the code less consistent;
- *never* set universal CSS properties on container widgets, as they will always be inherited by all its children; always use [selectors](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-syntax.html#selector-types) instead;
- it's normally discouraged to call `self.show()` (or `self.setVisible(True)`) within the `__init__` of a widget; for example, you may have to create an instance of a subclass that isn't shown until needed, but if you add `self.show()` in the super class `__init__` there is no way to prevent it;
- naming is an important part of programming, and should **never** be underestimated; classes and constants should have capitalized names, while only variable/function/method/attribute names should start with underscore characters, so that you can easily tell them apart while reading code; read more about these and other important aspects in the official [Style Guide for Python Code](//python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008);
- I strongly urge you to do some more careful research and studying about classes, instances, inheritance, and the meaning of `self`; start with basic, simple examples using normal python objects before using Qt objects, so that you can focus on the fundamental concepts before moving into the much more complex context of Qt objects;

Comment: Wicked cool! Great explanation and thank you for your time! I'll keep playing around with it.